# Rails 4 model formatting and hashes (really basic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this basic validation in my model:

```
  validates :student_number, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 255 },
                    :uniqueness => true
```

So what is all that? Here's my best guess, if you would kindly tell me where I'm mistaken, I'd appreciate it.

`validates` is a method. I send it the symbol `:first_name`, then `:presence => true`, which is...a hash with `:presence` for a key and `true` as a value?

Except it doesn't really look like a hash, at least not according to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html).

And then `:length => { :maximum => 255 }` is the same sort of entity (hash?) as `:presence => true` but it expects another hash as an argument?

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby allows you to drop parentheses and brackets if it can infer their locations by itself; in your case, you could rewrite the code as:

```
validates(:student_number, { :presence => true,
                             :length => { :maximum => 255 },
                             :uniqueness => true })
```

which is a method call, passing a first argument which is the attribute to validate, and a second argument which is the validation options, a hash.

Note: This explanation is a bit of a simplification, validates is actually a bit more complicated in how it handles its arguments. See [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates) for more details on how this works exactly.

Comment: Yup. That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, there is only one Hash, for a total of two arguments. (@crowhill seemed unclear on whether `:presence` and `:length` were parts of the same Hash or separate ones; I've edited the formatting on this answer slightly to make it clearer.)

Answer (score 0):

close but not close enough. All `:presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 255 }, :uniqueness => true` is ONE hash with three keys `presence, length, uniqueness` and three coresponding values. In fact it is the same as you would write 
`{ :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 255 }, :uniqueness => true }` but first way is shorter